# How to change size of one tab in tab layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Like the new UI of WhatsApp where camera icon (1st tab) is having small width and all other 3 tabs are having same width. How can we achieve same in tab layout ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446133/different-sized-tabs-with-tablayout-android

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom layout for the tab and set the dimension whatever you want
and inflate that layout and set the custom view method with this inflated layout

```
View customView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null); 
Tab tab=new TabLayout.Tab()
tab.setCustomView(customView)
mLayout.addTab(tab)
```